# SublimeRepl not syncing with code (runs old code)

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I have set keybinding Ctrl+Alt+B to run code in sublimeREPL. But, recently when I run a code it wont show the last change I have made to my code. I have to first Ctrl+B and then do Ctrl+Alt+B to run properly
Code:

```
print("Hello") 
print("added this line just now, this wont show up")
```

the line which was added later won't sync, it just runs the old code
[image: the line which was added later won't sync, it just runs the old code]

Answer (score -1):

Finally figured it out. I just had to turn on autosave. You can turn it on and it should be fixed. (methods are different for mac and windows, just search in youtube and everything will be alright)
Regards!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).